# Getting data into array

Tags: laravel

I'm working on some e-commerce website based on merchant. There is problem comping in submitting order. the problem is when i'm selecting same merchant that time order will be stored successfully, but when i'm selecting multiple product from different merchant that time my function through error of Undefined offset:1. Here is my function.

```
public function post_order(){
    $data = Input::all();
    $count = count($data['invoice_no']);
    $order = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
        if(!empty($data['invoice_no'][$i])){
            array_push($order, array(
                'order_no'          => $data['order_no'][$i],
                'invoice_prefix'    => $data['invoice_prefix'][$i],
                'invoice_no'        => $data['invoice_no'][$i],
                'merchant_id'       => $data['merchant_id'][$i],
                'customer_id'       => $data['customer_id'][$i],
                'buytokri_order'    => $data['order_name'][$i],
                'name'              => $data['name'][$i],
                'pincode'           => $data['pincode'][$i],
                'address'           => $data['address'][$i],
                'landmark'          => $data['landmark'][$i],
                'city'              => $data['city'][$i],
                'state'             => $data['state'][$i],
                'country'           => $data['country'][$i],
                'mobile'            => $data['mobile'][$i],
                'subtotal'          => $data['selling_price'][$i],
                'payment_type'      => $data['payment_type'][$i],
                'txn_id'            => $data['txn'][$i],
                'shipping'          => $data['shipping'][$i],
                'total'             => $data['subtotal'][$i]
            ));
        }
    }
    Order::insert($order);
    $var = $data['order_no'];
    foreach ($var as $vars) {
        $id = DB::table('ads_order')->where('order_no', $vars)->get();
    }
$count = count($data['invoice_no']);
    $orderhistory = array();
    for($i=0; $i<=$count; $i++){
        if(!empty($data['invoice_no'][$i])){
            array_push($orderhistory, array(                    
                'order_id'          => $id[$i]->id,
                'merchant_id'       => $data['merchant_id'][$i],
                'customer_id'       => $data['customer_id'][$i],
                'order_status'      => $data['order_status'][$i],
                'comment'           => $data['comment'][$i],
                'notify'            => $data['notify'][$i],
                'default'           => $data['default'][$i],
                'status'            => $data['status'][$i]
            ));             
        }
    }
    Orderhistory::insert($orderhistory);
return Redirect::intended('/ordersuccess');
}
```

Comment: what have you done to debug it so far?

Comment: Oh boy DB::table we meet again.
You not using any models?
What's the reason for using loop instead of doing foreach on $id?
Can $id be changed to something meaningful as in $orderCollection?
what happens when you do dd($id)?